# How can I draw a random thickness curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, regions

As we know that add weight factors to `Tube`, we can get variety thickness tube.  I want to know how to do the same thing directly in **2D graph** instead of only a 3D graph with top viewpoint, for example, make a `Bezier Curve` variety thickness.

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}};
tube = Graphics3D[{Red, 
    Tube[BezierCurve[PadRight[#, 3] & /@ pts], 
     RandomReal[{0.1, .5}, Length@pts]]}, ViewPoint -> Top, 
   ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Boxed -> False];
GraphicsRow[{tube, ImageMesh[ColorNegate[tube], Frame -> True]}]
```

[image]

### Edit

I want a **Random**  thickness and **BezierCurve** instead of normal function. For example, an arbitrary `BezierCurve`.

```
pts1 = {{5, -2}, {0, 0}, {1, 2}, {5, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}};
pts2 = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1.2, 2}, {.6, 1.8}, {0, 1.3}, {-.6, 
    1.8}, {-1.2, 2}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}};
{Graphics[BezierCurve[pts1]], Graphics[BezierCurve[pts2]]}
```

[image]

Comment: For a review of potentially helpful techniques, see [28202](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/vary-the-thickness-of-a-plotted-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A starting point.
- Use some ideas from my previous answer. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296061/72111

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}};
n = 100;
plot0 = ListLinePlot[
   MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeGraphics@BezierCurve@pts], 
   MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {n}];
p = Cases[plot0[[1]], GraphicsComplex[{pts__}, __] :> pts, -1];
meshindexs = First@Cases[plot0[[1]], Point[i_] :> i, -1];
meshPoints = Join[{pts[[1]]}, p[[meshindexs]], {pts[[-1]]}];
right = #1 + 
    RandomReal[{0.1, .5}]*
     Normalize[RotationTransform[-(π/2), #1][#2] - #1] &;
left = #1 + 
    RandomReal[{0.1, .5}]*
     Normalize[RotationTransform[π/2, #1][#2] - #1] &;
pts1 := right @@@ Partition[meshPoints, 2, 1];
corner1[base_, end_] := 
  Table[base + 
    RandomReal[{.1, .5}]*
     Normalize[RotationTransform[t, base][end] - base], {t, 
    Subdivide[-(π/2), π/2, 4]}];
pts2 := left @@@ Partition[meshPoints, 2, 1];
g := Graphics[{Orange, 
   FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve[pts1[[{1, Sequence @@ Range[2, n, 5]}]], 
      SplineDegree -> 6], 
     BSplineCurve[corner1[meshPoints[[-2]], meshPoints[[-1]]], 
      SplineDegree -> 6], 
     BSplineCurve[Reverse@pts2[[{1, Sequence @@ Range[2, n, 5]}]], 
      SplineDegree -> 4], Line[{pts2[[1]], pts[[1]], pts1[[1]]}]}], 
   Blue, BezierCurve@pts}]

GraphicsGrid[{{g, g}, {g, g}}]
```

[image]

- another attempt

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}};
curve = BezierCurve@pts;
(* RegionQ[curve] *)
reg = DiscretizeGraphics@curve;
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = RegionBounds[reg];
dist = RegionDistance[reg];
nearest = RegionNearest[reg];
plot = ContourPlot[
   dist@{x, y}, {x, x1 - 1, x2 + 1}, {y, y1 - 1, y2 + 1}, 
   Contours -> {.3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourShading -> None];
data = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, -1];
tran[pts_] := Module[{n, k, data},
  n = Length@pts;
  k = Floor[0.05 n];
  data = pts[[1 ;; -1 ;; k]];
  Graphics[{Orange, 
    FilledCurve@
     BSplineCurve[
      ReplacePart[data, 
       Table[i -> 
         data[[i]] + 
          RandomReal[{1, 2}]*(data[[i]] - nearest@data[[i]]), {i, 
         Range[Length@data][[1 ;; -1 ;; k]]}]], SplineDegree -> 4, 
      SplineClosed -> True]}]]
Show[tran /@ data, Graphics[{Blue, curve}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use `Black` and `Glow[Red]` instead of just `Red`.

Also use `Deploy@Graphics3D` to disable rotation by mouse so that the output is just like output of `Graphics`. Or `Method -> {"RotationControl" -> None}` inside `Graphicd3D` can be used to disable rotation by mouse.

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}};
Graphics3D[{Black, Glow[Red], 
  Tube[BezierCurve[PadRight[#, 3] & /@ pts], 
   RandomReal[{0.1, .5}, Length@pts]]}, ViewPoint -> Top, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Boxed -> False]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can be done normally by filling between two curves

```
  Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] + 0.02 x^2}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> ( Hue[#2/2] &), Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
        FillingStyle -> Automatic ]
```

[image]